# Implementation of PayPal and Apple Pay

Tags: ios, swift, paypal, applepay

I want implementation of apple pay and paypal both. if I am implementing Applepay through Braintree and paypal by sdk then I am finding duplicate symbolic error.

if I am implementing both method through brain tree then I am finding Braintree.h file not find. when install the pod.

Is both implementation possible? if yes then please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Well need more details to say about error. But yes for payment option keep following in mind,

Payment option depends on what context(i.e what product) you are using it. If you have non-physical goods than InAppPurchase is recommended but if it is physical goods than you can use Payment gateways.

If you want to implement Applepay and Paypal both I suggest you to use both non-natively i.e. open a webview in the app and perform your payment outside the app. For Apple Pay you can use Stripe Api for that.

The reason behind is that Apple does not allow PayPal to use natively as recommended payment option is to use Applepay whereas Paypal does not include Apple pay. [read this](http://bankinnovation.net/2014/09/missing-from-the-paypal-ipo-apple-pay/).
Also see, If you are using Stripe natively for payment then your payment confirmation is done outside the app(i.e. using your server api) after getting token of payment details.[read this](https://www.devsaran.com/blog/detailed-guideline-integrating-stripe-ios-apps-using-swift)

So why use native implementation if your job is finally implementing outside the app. Just use webview implementation for both and perform your payment outside the app.